# How to use GET method of Requests to look for unfinished urls?

Tags: python, get, python-requests

For example, I need to get every image displayed on a page while knowing the address they're stored at. The method I'm looking for will allow using `https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/*` Where * is a random link that I can make a list of or just download.

```
import requests as req

phot = req.get('https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7987513770b3cfa32372114cde65ff7d/5D53D9CA/t51.2885-15/e35/57306185_137865170666087_417139389797653381_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com')

with open('sea.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(phot.content)
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Do you want to be able to provide a URL with an asterisk in it and have requests grab all objects at that path? Or do you want to be able to provide a "list" of paths with a common base URL for requests to go and grab all of them?

Comment: A list of all the urls taht start with the same address.

Comment: You're going to need to retrieve the list of image links using web scraping first.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish what you are describing by creating a function that takes the `base_url` and a list of paths to resources to download:

```py
import requests as req

def get_resources(base_url, resource_paths):
    responses = [req.get(base_url + path) for path in resource_paths]

res = get_resource('http://example.com/', ['img1', 'img2', 'etc'])
# This would fetch the following resources:
# - 'http://example.com/img1'
# - 'http://example.com/img2'
# - 'http://example.com/etc'
```